# Android Studio, color in selector (in item) doesnt work

Tags: java, android, colors, selector

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/sort_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundless_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#2A56C6"
        android:text="@string/order_by_time"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sort_status"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/IndBlue"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        </shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/IndBlue" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

I tried to edit the buttons colors, but for some reason it won't change. Solid android:color / android:drawable doesn't work even though I placed it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

when you use selector as button background it inherits the color from theme. you can try changing the theme primary color and that will affect the button color.